# Distinguish causal effect from vitamin supplementation from natural vitamin on negative outcome from vitamin supplementation

Tags: machine-learning, biostatistics, bioinformatics

Hi I will be very grateful for any help or ideas or hints. I have searched the internet but no suggestion seems to be able to help me. I am a  bioinformatician and I mostly work with R. I have a dataset of over 20  thousand non-randomised observations which contains values for a  vitamin, say vitamin y values alongside BMI, age, sex information, and information whether or not a person received vit y supplementation.  Vitamin y supplement, is commonly prescribed against stomach pain. In  our observed data, we realise that 25% of those who take vitamin y  supplementation rather develop stomach pain. We also realise that 18% of  those who do not receive supplementation for vitamin y also complain about stomack pain. I want to perform a causal analysis to differentiate if it is vitamin y, also important in the body functions   that causes the stomach pain or it is the supplementation that causes  the stomach pain. I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Would you say that the individuals who supplement themselves all have a noticeably higher level of the vitamin than the individuals who do not ? Or is there substantial overlap between the values ?

Comment: @CaroZ Yes, a t.test shows that the supplemented group has a significantly  higher amount of the vitamin.